# C# Top and Groupby missing from sql query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I am currently optimizing a function that is not meeting our performance requirements.  It was using lazy loading which was causing the function to run very slow with not that many items in the list.

The main table I'm querying is a table that has a schema of:

(Id, ParentId, ChildId)

This could be represented like
<1, 1, 2>
<2, 2, 1>
where there is a bidirectional relationship.

Now with this query, I'm trying to group on the connected item and the value is the list of connections.  Also, I would like the potentially only get the top value of this to also be a performance increase.

Here is my scrubbed code:

```
var connections = _context.Entity
    .Include(x => x.ParentFK.Select(y => y.Parent))
    .Include(x => x.ChildFK.Select(y => y.Child))
    .First(x => x.Id == id)
    .Parents
    .Concat(entity.Children)
    .GroupBy(connection => connection.ChildId == entity.Id ? connection.Parent : connection.Child, conn => conn)
    .Take(7)
    .ToList();
```

In this query, the TOP of the sql is missing as well as the groupby, which makes me believe that all the data is brought into memory, then grouped and topped.

How can I get this all in the sql query itself?

Thanks!

Update: I rearranged some of the query and made it much simpler.  Yet, I still don't see a top or group by clause in the generated SQL.

```
    var connections1 = _context.Connections
    .Include(x => x.Parent)
    .Include(x => x.Child)
    .Where(x => x.ChildId == entity.Id || x.ParentId == entity.Id)
    .GroupBy(connection => connection.ChildId == entity.Id ? connection.Parent : connection.Child, conn => conn)
    .Take(7)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What's the compile-time type of `Parents`?

Comment: What do you mean 'the TOP is missing'? What is the generated SQL query?

Comment: Wow - where are  `Group` and `Take` applied? That `First()` call actually *executes* the query. That's not a quirk of EF - that's an explicit request to get the first result of the list. Everything after that works on that single object

Comment: Parents is a virtual ICollection<Connection>.  Also, the generated SQL query is quite large.  Basically, it's doing a lot of joins and selected a ton of columns, which is quite fine and expected.  I was hoping to see a groupby clause at the bottom of the query and a top clause at the... top. haha

Comment: As for performance, the proper schema, types and indexes the most importan factors. A parent-child table will always be slower than a table using a `hierarchyid` field. You can create views and/or functions that return entities and their children, and map your entities to them

Comment: hmmm.. that's true. It may be First that does execute the query.  Maybe I need to re-arrange some things.

Comment: @MatthewHartz not "may", does. You can't write in LINQ to EF something that doesn't make sense in SQL. `First(..)` corresponds to `TOP 1 ... WHERE ...`. Would it make sense to add extra grouping, UNION and TOP to that?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think I realized a way to tackle it.  Basically, i'm coming at it from the wrong direction.  I should be using _context.Connections.Where(x => x.ParentId == id || x.ChildId == id)...  there i can include the correct entities and potentially group on it there.  If that works, ill accept you as the answer and update my question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated the entity query, does that make sense to still not see anything?

Comment: Where *is* the generated query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148980/discussion-between-matthew-hartz-and-panagiotis-kanavos).